# Sortino ratio lower than sharpe ratio?

Tags: sharpe-ratio

Under what circumstances is a sortino ratio lower than a sharpe ratio? What does it mean about the distribution?

Comment: distribution of the portfolio returns?

Comment: Yes. And how can it be understood intuitively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whereas the *Sharpe ratio* divides the risk premium (mean excess return) by the volatility, the *Sortino ratio* instead divides by semideviation: the standard deviation computed using only negative returns.

For perfectly symmetric return distributions, these should not differ much. However, if a return distribution has skewness, then the Sortino ratio may be very different. In this case, a smaller Sortino ratio means a larger semideviation -- so a negatively-skewed return distribution. When we look at log-returns for individual stocks, such negative skewness is not unusual for a number of economic reasons.